# Why does repeating a list not reference but copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> L = [4, 5, 6]
>>> X = L * 4                    
>>> X
[4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]
>>> L[1] = 0
```

Why

```
>>> X
[4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]
```

instead of

```
>>> X
[4, 0, 6, 4, 0, 6, 4, 0, 6, 4, 0, 6]
```

?

What function or method is called when `L * 4` is evaluated?

- `L.copy()`,
- `list(L)`,
- `copy.copy(L)`
- or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Huh? The references *are* copied.  Please read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: The additional code complexity and overhead of making it possible for `L * 4` to be backed by `L` isn't worth it.

Answer (score 4):

When `L * 4` is called, the under-the-hood machinery that is called is something like the following Python code:

```
>>> L = [4, 5, 6]
>>> N = 4
>>> new = [x for _ in range(N) for x in L]  # i.e. L * N
>>> # Alternatively...
>>> new = []
>>> for _ in range(N):
...     for x in L:
...         new.append(x)
...
```

Which means each element is a reference to the original, but a new list object is created.  It's not really like any of `L.copy()`, `list(L)`, or `copy.copy(L)`.

Let's look at how this is implemented under-the-hood. Here is what happens in CPython when the `*` operator is encountered.:

```
    TARGET(BINARY_MULTIPLY) {
        PyObject *right = POP();
        PyObject *left = TOP();
        PyObject *res = PyNumber_Multiply(left, right);
        Py_DECREF(left);
        Py_DECREF(right);
        SET_TOP(res);
        if (res == NULL)
            goto error;
        DISPATCH();
    }
```

In the `PyNumber_Multiply` function, if number multiplication fails it assumes that one of the objects is a sequence and thus ends up (after a bit of indirection) calling [`list_repeat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/listobject.c#L510) (this is an oversimplification, see first comment for more details). Here is the code

```
static PyObject *
list_repeat(PyListObject *a, Py_ssize_t n)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, j;
    Py_ssize_t size;
    PyListObject *np;
    PyObject **p, **items;
    PyObject *elem;
    if (n < 0)
        n = 0;
    if (n > 0 && Py_SIZE(a) > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX / n)
        return PyErr_NoMemory();
    size = Py_SIZE(a) * n;
    if (size == 0)
        return PyList_New(0);
    np = (PyListObject *) PyList_New(size);  // <== Make a new list of the expanded size
    if (np == NULL)
        return NULL;

    items = np->ob_item;
    if (Py_SIZE(a) == 1) {  // <== Optimization for L * 1
        elem = a->ob_item[0];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            items[i] = elem;
            Py_INCREF(elem);
        }
        return (PyObject *) np;
    }
    p = np->ob_item;
    items = a->ob_item;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {  // <== Reference the original elements in the new list in the appropriate locations.
        for (j = 0; j < Py_SIZE(a); j++) {
            *p = items[j];
            Py_INCREF(*p);
            p++;
        }
    }
    return (PyObject *) np;
}
```

As you can see, it first allocates a new list and then makes a reference of *each object* of the list into the new list, rather than simply creating several references of the original.  So, each element of the list is a reference to the original element, but the list itself is not a reference to the original.

Comment: To clarify the phrasing that `PyNumber_Multiply` assumes that either object is a sequence, what it actually does is check whether the left-hand operand's type defines `tp_as_sequence->sq_repeat` and the right-hand operand can be converted to an integer index, or vice versa. Otherwise it's an error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `X` is not modified is because

```
X = L * 4
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
X = L.__mul__(4)
```

The `__mul__` function is what Python calls under the hood when using the `*` operator. It returns a *new object*:

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> id(l.__mul__(4)) == id(l)
False
>>>
```

So `X` holds a reference to the new object returned by `L.__mul__(4)`, rather than a reference to object `L` is referencing. Basically, `X` and `L` reference completely different list objects, so changing one variables reference does not affect the other's.

Note that while Python does not make a copy of the reference `L` holds, it does create copies of references to each *element* in the list object `L` refers to. That's why multiplying sublist leads to unexpected behavior:

```
>>> l = [[0]*2]*2
>>> l
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> l[0][0] = 1
>>> l
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It *does* copy references. See:

```
In [14]: L = [4, 5, 6]

In [15]: fourL = 4*L

In [16]: [hex(id(i)) for i in L]
Out[16]: ['0x1002148d0', '0x1002148f0', '0x100214910']

In [17]: [hex(id(i)) for i in fourL]
Out[17]:
['0x1002148d0',
 '0x1002148f0',
 '0x100214910',
 '0x1002148d0',
 '0x1002148f0',
 '0x100214910',
 '0x1002148d0',
 '0x1002148f0',
 '0x100214910',
 '0x1002148d0',
 '0x1002148f0',
 '0x100214910']
```